# Certificate status still pending even after completion

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, exchange-2013, certutil

I have exchange 2013 on Azure VM which is also a DC. for using services like autodiscover etc I need to get a valid 3rd Party certificate which I got from STARTSSL, I generated the request and got the certificate downloaded along with private key from STARTSSL. I clicked complete and import the certificate still it says status pending. I also tried the certufil -repairstore my "thumbprint" but it asks for smart card which I cant as my Machine is on AZURE VM, can anyone help please ?

Here is an image about it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks to me like the certificate didn't install correctly. Not unusual. You could try downloading the certificate again and see if it will install correctly a second time. Otherwise it will have to be a new request within Exchange so you get a fresh key pair.

You shouldn't have Exchange on a domain controller either...

Comment: in last 3-4 days i tried this process about 15-20 times, i've been working on it all day and night, I generated CSR through EAC and Powershell, each time they would go pending, when i check the certificate from certmgr it doesnt show any private key associated with it, when i run get-exchangecertificate "thumbprint" it says special rpc error this thumbprint has been found but no private key is missing. certutil is giving above error, i also tried importing the certificate in .pfx format but still doesn't work, it remains in pending status. generated csr request through EAC and PS, but no use

Comment: Why not try a free trial certificate from Comodo or one of the others. That will allow you to confirm that the server is working correctly.

Comment: I installed local CA and after generating request from my local CA, it accepted and validated the server and i was able to assign services to it. but even trying 10-15 times from startssl it doesn't work, i think the issue is with startssl's certificate, let me try comodo free trial and get back to you after results

Comment: ahh leave comodo, is it possible for you to help me by skype call/ screensharing ?